# How can I check for a digit or character in an SQL table column?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I feel like this question has to have been answered somewhere, but I read through tons of posts and tried many variations of solutions and I can't get this to work.

I have a database table called `schedule` and I simply want to select the rows that contain a specific digit from the `days` column using python.  The days column contains some combination of numbers from 1 to 7 each representing a day of the week.  It could be a single day, or a combination of days("1", "135", "1234567", etc).

Given a specific day index (e.g. 3), I want to select all the rows from schedule that have a 3 in the days column.

I made the column type VARCHAR, because I figured it would be easier to check a string than an integer value.

This is my current statement, where day is the index (e.g. 3) of the selected day:

```
"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE CONTAINS(days, '{}')".format(day)
```

I continually get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(days, '3')'
```

What can I fix to make this work?

Comment: Why are you using contains instead of days = {}?

Comment: Because days could contain all the possible days I wan't to execute the event on, so if the event is done every day, days would be "1234567"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use MySQL?

MySQL doesn't have 'CONTAINS' operator, use 'LIKE' operator.

```
"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE days LIKE '%{}%'".format(day)
```

`%` is the wildcard character that can be any characters.

Answer (score 0):

So if you take your string of days and split them so that you get a list and then you can use the IN statement to select for any of the values.

So let's say you have:

```
days = '1234567'
```

Convert this to a list.

```
days = days.split('')  # Split on an empty string to split each character.
```

Then your SQL looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE days in ({})".format(days)
```

The select will search for any values in a given array. The format is just inserting the python array. Also this will work even if the original value of days is only one day. i.e. days = '1'